# Getting error “SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when run the code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

i try to run this code on my raspberry pi 3 but i get this problem

i tried to uninstall telegram library but he said E: Unable to locate package telegram

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py2.7.egg/telegram/ext/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .updater import Updater
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py2.7.egg/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 33, in <module>
    from telegram.utils.webhookhandler import (WebhookServer, WebhookAppClass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-12.0.0b1-py2.7.egg/telegram/utils/webhookhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-6.0.2-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/tornado/httpserver.py", line 144
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i tried to uninstall telegram library but he said
 E: Unable to locate package telegram

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/395

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
led = 5
DHT_pin = 27

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT, initial = 0)
# Enable logging
#logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
 #                   level=logging.INFO)

#logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments bot and
# update. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def on(bot, update):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
    update.message.reply_text('LED turned ON')

def off(bot, update):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)
    update.message.reply_text('LED turned OFF')

def hum(bot, update):
    """Send a message when the command /hum is issued."""
    humidity = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, DHT_pin)[0]
    update.message.reply_text("Humidity: {} %".format(humidity))

def temp(bot, update):
    """Send a message when the command /temp is issued."""
    temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, DHT_pin)[1]
    update.message.reply_text("Temperature: {} C".format(temperature))

def echo(bot, update):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def error(bot, update, error):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, error)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("Enter your token here")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("on", on))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("off", off))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("temp", temp))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("hum", hum))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to run the code using Python2? The syntax error complains about the type annotations used in the library code. These typing hints were introduced in Python3.5.

Comment: sorry but im new to programming,, so how i can make raspberry run it in Python3.5 ??

Comment: Perhaps you can start your script using: `python3 my script.py`

Comment: i get this now :
 sudo python3 main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: No module named 'telegram'

Comment: Ah, probably you installed telegram using `pip install telegram`, is that correct? That defaults apparently to `pip2` on your system. Try installing using `pip3 install telegram` instead and then try to run your script again.

Comment: thats right .. Now i tried pip3 install telegram and i see the folder in (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages) but in cmd i get this :
 sudo python3 main.py   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: No module named 'telegram.ext'

Comment: I googled your error: "No module named 'telegram.ext'" and came across this [answer](https://github.com/xdavidhu/lanGhost/issues/7#issuecomment-368316325). I assumed (wrongly) that the package you used is called `telegram` while in fact I now assume it is called `python-telegram-bot`. So try this: `pip3 install python-telegram-bot`. Does that help?

Comment: Ah I now see in your original post that you in fact do use the `python-telegram-bot` package, so the above comment should fix your issue I think.

Comment: it give same problem :
sudo python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: No module named 'telegram.ext'

and when im looking in my manger file (python 2.7) have this file but (python 3.5) doesn't.

Comment: Yeah so that should mean that you installed `python-telegram-bot` using `pip` or `pip2`, which installs it for `python` or `python2`. Now you want to install it using `pip3`, like this: `pip3 install python-telegram-bot`, so you can use it with `python3`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Hmm and if you use `pip3.5` and `python3.5`?

Comment: sudo python3.5 install python-telegram-bot
python3.5: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I mean `pip3.5 install python-telegram-bot` followed by `sudo python3.5 main.py`

Comment: when i try pip3.5 install python-telegram-bot
-bash: pip3.5: command not found

Comment: i try to uninstall this folder (python-telegram-bot) from pi folder and try to install it again by 
`
git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot --recursive
 cd python-telegram-bot
 python3 setup.py install
`
and i saw the file .ext in python 3.5 but also i get same problem

Comment: And if you try using a virtual environment? Perhaps Google it if you don't know how to use one.

Comment: i delete telegram by :
pip uninstall telegram
pip3 uninstall telegram
and install telegram bot 
pip install python-telegram-bot